# How might casinos guard against psionic cheaters?

Tags: psionics

The idea is that at some point in the near (or maybe distant) future people developing psychic/psychokinetic talents are widely known to exist and those who run gambling institutions are concerned such abilities might be used to cheat at the tables- what are some possible ways to safeguard against this happening?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what psy-something talents exist, what they can do and what options there are for blocking/jamming those powers, we can't answer this.  Powers could range from telekinesis to affect dice or roulette (eg Jason dinAlt in the Deathworld books) to clairvoyance or telepathy to view other players' cards, to precognition to see what will happen to teleport/transmutation powers to swap or change cards or dice - that's just off the top of my head.  More details required.

Comment: If you're talking strictly about telekynesis I'd suggest embedding sensors inside dices and other things that can be moved that can detect any unnatural movement after someone let go of them.

Comment: Exactly the same way they guard against card counters, careful attention to each customers success rate and winnings over time, banning those who are too successful, distributing their mugshots throughout their own casinos and sharing it with others in return for them sharing theirs with you .. a well established tried and fully tested method with a proven track record of working, so why would you need anything else?

Comment: The business model of casinos is to provide entertainment (games of chance) that people pay for. That means that they can and do kick out people who are not paying for the entertainment. It doesn't matter why the person is not paying for it (cheating, psy., etc.) It only matters that the casino is not profitable offering that entertainment to that person.